# ruby-mode not indenting correctly?

Tags: ruby-mode, ruby

I am using `emacs 24.4` in `-nw` terminal mode. I know `ruby-mode` is included but I cannot get the following snippet to indent correctly in a `.rb` file.

```
private
    def
    end
```

Instead I can only get

```
private
def
end
```

Comment: This [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7777032/1167324) may explain what you experience. TL;DR: `ruby-mode` does not indent after `private` by default, conforming to the .[ruby style guide](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide) recomendations.

Comment: Thanks @theldoria, that seems to be what was causing my confusion! :D